# Ant fileset matching only files but excluding all sub directories

Tags: ant

How do I copy only files immediately under the directory and not its subdirectories? I don't know a priori the names of the files or the subdirectories.  I've tried the following to no avail:

```
<include name="*">  # includes all files and subdirs
===
<include name="*">
<exclude name="*/**> # or "*/" or "**"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I ended up just adding a delete task to delete the copied subdirectories:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${targetdir}">
        <type type="dir"/>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="copy-top-most-files-only" name="My Project">

    <property name="to.dir" value="/path/to/dest/folder/" />
    <property name="from.dir" value="/path/to/source/folder/" />

    <target name="copy-top-most-files-only">
        <copy todir="${to.dir}" includeEmptyDirs="false" >
            <fileset dir="${from.dir}">
                <exclude name="*/**/*" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still copied the subdirectories under the fileset dir.

Comment: Could you post your full copy task?  Exclusions can get "overruled" by inclusions if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to specify a [`<depth>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#depthselect) selector, for example:

```
<copy todir="dest">
    <fileset dir="src">
        <depth max="0" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

That will prevent subdirectories from being copied.

You can combine selectors with include/exclude rules if needed.

Comment: Thanks but this still copied the subdirectories. I even added type="file" selector to no avail.